# facing issue while setting up angular project in local from gitlab(not able to install npm locally)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
npm WARN deprecated node-fetch-npm@2.0.2: This module is not used anymore, npm uses minipass-fetch for its fetch implementation now
npm WARN deprecated streamroller@1.0.6: 1.x is no longer supported. Please upgrade to 3.x or higher.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @schematics/update@0.803.25: This was an internal-only Angular package up through Angular v11 which is no longer used or maintained. Upgrade Angular to v12+ to remove this dependency.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated angular2-useful-swiper@8.0.1-beta.1: this package has now been renamed to ngx-useful-swiper please use that package from now on
npm WARN deprecated log4js@4.5.1: 4.x is no longer supported. Please upgrade to 6.x or higher.
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.18.1: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information,
npm WARN deprecated protractor@5.4.3: We have news to share - Protractor is deprecated and will reach end-of-life by Summer 2023. To learn more and find out about other options please refer to this post on the Angular blog. Thank you for using and contributing to
Protractor.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@3.6.2: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@3.6.4: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path F:\Oyebusy\oyebusy_web\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=F:\Oyebusy\oyebusy_web\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=F:\Oyebusy\oyebusy_web\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.14.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "F:\Oyebusy\oyebusy_web\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404):
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.24.2 and node@16.15.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:330:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:159:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:228:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:294:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:418:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=F:\Oyebusy\oyebusy_web\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=F:\Oyebusy\oyebusy_web\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd F:\Oyebusy\oyebusy_web\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=F:\Oyebusy\oyebusy_web\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=F:\Oyebusy\oyebusy_web\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (F:\Oyebusy\oyebusy_web\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "F:\Oyebusy\oyebusy_web\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd F:\Oyebusy\oyebusy_web\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\komal\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-10-21T17_46_02_305Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all express the problem in an organized way to get a helpful answer.
Well, make sure the package.json file is present in the same directory. Open terminal and Run

> npm i

if the above doesn't work, try

> npm i --force